# Can a linear transformation going from one vector space to another have eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, linear-transformations

Usually eigenvalues are defined as $T:V \rightarrow V$ from one vector space to itself. But if we consider a vector space in 2D space $V = span\{(1, 0)\}$ and another vector space $W = V^{\perp}$, we get a new linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow W$ which is a linear transformation from one vector space to another. Now I consider the $90^{\circ}$ 2D rotation matrix as the matrix of the linear transformation, $\left( \begin{matrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{matrix} \right)$, so that I have a linear transformation from one vector space to a different vector space with eigenvalues.

My question is, is what I did correct? And is my statement correct? Can linear transformations into a different vector space have eigenvalues?

Comment: Only if W contains V.

Answer (score 2):

Eigenvectors of a linear transformation T are those vectors v, for which T(v) is a scalar multiple of v.  As scalar multiples of v are in the same vector space as V, it does not make sense to talk of eigenvectors when dealing with a linear transformation from one vector space to a different one.   And so eigenvalues are also undefinable in that case.

Comment: I feel as though if the transformation was from a subspace of a vector space V to V itself that reasoning might not hold. Strictly speaking it would still be a transformation between different vector spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the eigenvector/value problem is to find the bases which diagonalize (or quasi-diagonalize) matrix representations of linear operators. The result of this makes iterative numerical procedures more efficient. To iterate of course, one would need the domain and codomain vector spaces to be the *same*.
That is not to say that $det(A-\lambda I_n)$ can't be calculated for two different vector spaces of the same dimension in some chosen bases. We would just need an interpretation that doesn't really align with the notion of the *action of a linear operator on a vector space*.
In your example, the rotation matrix actually effects the whole of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the fixed direction is orthogonal to this plane. In other words $T:V\to V$ where $V = \mathbb{R}^2$. This operator, when viewed in $V = \mathbb{R}^3$ with the standard basis, looks like:
$$A = [T]_{\beta_{std.}} = \begin{bmatrix}0&& -1&& 0\\1&& 0&& 0\\0&&0 && 1\end{bmatrix},$$
from which it is more apparent (by the block form) that the hidden subspace is $T$-invariant.

Comment: How about the identity function with domain the space of real numbers over the field of real numbers and codomain the space of complex numbers over the field of real numbers.

Comment: Nvm actually. Strictly speaking that doesn't work.

Comment: Actually I think it does so long as you are viewing the reals as being the set of all complex numbers with imaginary component equal to zero. So your domain becomes the embedding of the reals into the complex numbers instead of the reals. In that casebI think you still have different domain and codomain but 1 is an eigenvalue.

Comment: So you are saying look at $\iota: \mathbb{R}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ provided by $a \mapsto a+0i$? Well this is linear no doubt. But choose bases for $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, say $\beta_1 := \{1\}$ and $\beta_2:=\{1,i\}$ resp., then the matrix would be $A := [\iota]_{\beta_1}^{\beta_2} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, which is not square. So we couldn't compute $det(A-\lambda I_2)$ to get $p(\lambda)$.

Comment: The map that I am talking about uses the range of your function as it's domain, but views the codomain as the vector space of complex numbers over thr field of real numbers.

Comment: Basically I am using the fact that an extension field forms a vector space over that field. So If F and E are fields, and F is a subset of E, then each of those fields is a vector space over F. I am then talking about the mapping from F into E that maps every element of F to itself. If F is a proper subset of E, then the domain and codomain are different but every non-zero element of F is an eigenvector with eigenvalues 1

Comment: Actually there might be dimensional issues now that I think about it. I haven't had any access to paper or a computer so haven't been able to write it out. I'm awful at doing math in my head

Comment: Yes it would definitely not work if you insisted the codomain have the same dimension as your domain, which I think may technically be required by the definition. Likely because you would need that in order for the determinant to be defined.